# Microsoft Remote Desktop <windows-ctrl> left and right arrow to select text by word still mapped to Mission Control

Tags: windows, shortcut, remote-desktop

I'm using Catalina and Microsoft Remote Desktop to tunnel in my PC running Windows 10 Pro.  I have a two monitor setup and I'm using both monitors on both systems.  It works amazingly well for my workflow.  Except for one annoying thing.  In Windows I use windows-ctrl->left-arrow and windows-ctrl->right-arrow to navigate text by word all the time.  And I'm often using my Logitech M720 mouse side button gesture to change Mission control spaces on my Mac.  This gesture is mapped to the same key combination I use in Windows.  I've tryied removing/changing the keyboard shortcut in Mac OS, but it breaks the gesture.  ***Is there a way to re-link the mouse side-button left and right swipe to a new keyboard shortcut on OS X?***  I'm open to ways to remap in Windows too, but have less flexibility in what I can do there as it's a work machine.

Also posted here: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/254977900

Comment: I've found this, which isn't perfect...https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/729258/remote-desktop-on-mac-microsoft-remote-desktop-dis